# how to add a node after a given node in circular linked list?

Tags: python, data-structures

Below is the code snippet to add a node after a given node. however, it's not working. As I understand the node is added in the same reference the way we add node in singly linked list. So, with few changes I tried to implement, but no use.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.nxt = self
        

class cirLL:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lst = None
        
    def addEnd(self, val):
        nu = Node(val)
        if self.lst is None:
            self.lst = nu
        else:
            nu.nxt = self.lst.nxt
            self.lst.nxt = nu
            self.lst = nu
    
  
    def addaftr(self, pos, val):
        tmp = self.lst.nxt
        while tmp != self.lst:
            if tmp.data == pos:
                break
            tmp = tmp.nxt
        if tmp is None:
            print(pos, "not present")
        else:
            nu = Node(val)
            nu.nxt = tmp.nxt
            tmp.nxt = nu
    
    def disply(self):
        if not self.lst:
            return  # nothing to print
        tmp = self.lst.nxt
        print(tmp.data)
        while tmp != self.lst:
            tmp = tmp.nxt
            print(tmp.data)
                
               
rew = cirLL()
rew.addaftr(30, 456)
rew.addEnd(23)
rew.addEnd(30)
rew.addEnd(90)
rew.disply()
```

I am getting below error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'nxt'
```

Not sure what could have gone wrong. Please suggest.

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: the class data member `lst` equals `None` you need to Initialize it first and just after that you can access its attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is quite clear:

```
    tmp = self.lst.nxt
```

The above statement *assumes* that `self.lst` is not `None`, but initially it is. Hence, you get the error you got.

Just like the `addEnd` method does, you should first test if `self.lst` is maybe `None` and act accordingly.

You can fix it as follows:

```
def addaftr(self, pos, val):
    if self.lst is None:
        print(pos, "not present")
        return
    # rest of your code
```

### Other remarks:

- The name `pos` is misleading. First I thought the method was intended to insert a node at a *position* in the list, but it turns out that `pos` is a list *value* and not a *position*.
- It is a bit odd that you want to insert a node after value **30**, when there is no node in your list yet. Did you really intend that?
- Another issue is that this condition will never be true:

  ```
  if tmp is None
  ```

  As your list is circular, `tmp` will just hit the `lst` node, but it will never become `None`. Moreover, your loop does not check whether maybe the *last* node in the list has the data you're looking for. That `if` should be replaced with:

  ```
  if tmp.data != pos:
  ```
- When the value to find happens to be at the last node, then after the insertion you need to adapt the `lst` reference to the newly inserted node. So at the end of the `else` block, add this:

  ```
      if tmp == self.lst:
          self.lst = nu
  ```

Here is the corrected code:

```
    def addaftr(self, findval, val):
        if self.lst is None:
            print(findval, "not present")
            return
        tmp = self.lst.nxt
        while tmp != self.lst:
            if tmp.data == findval:
                break
            tmp = tmp.nxt
        if tmp.data != findval:
            print(findval, "not present")
        else:
            nu = Node(val)
            nu.nxt = tmp.nxt
            tmp.nxt = nu
            if tmp == self.lst:
                self.lst = nu
```

Comment: I have tried, but the code isn't working. I tried to add a new node after the existing node 30. But when I use the addAftr() method. it gives me an error "30 not present". Please suggest

Comment: But you call it when the list is empty. At that moment there is no 30 yet in your list.

Comment: It works fine if your main program **first** inserts the value 30 and **then** calls `addafr(30, 456)`. You can see it running on [repl.it](https://replit.com/@trincottrincots/httpsstackoverflowcoma739870735459839#main.py)

Comment: Yes, it works, I was calling the addAftr before adding 30. Thank you.